# Functions that go up two and then down two

Tags: functions, plane-curves

I'm trying to make a function that goes up two and then down two (kind of like sin(x) but without the curves). I keep drawing a blank on what I can do to even create this functions as I haven't done this type of work in a long time. Maybe theres some piecewise function that can be defined but i'm drawing a blank

Comment: Do you want a triangle wave or a square wave? [comparison](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Waveforms.svg)

Comment: see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28mod%28x%2C4%29-2%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing something called a Triangle Wave.  There are several different ways to write it.  One of the easiest to describe would be using piecewise defined using the fractional part of $x$  (defined as $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$)

Other possible patterns include square waves and sawtooth waves, depending on what it is you want.

Play around with the fractional part of $x$ and horizontal and vertical stretch and vertical shifts, as well as its negative to get a triangle wave that fits your exact image in your mind.

[image]

image taken from wikipedia

Comment: in case you are curious, the post by @graydad below describes a squarewave.  Note that squarewaves are not continuous, but they do fill the criterion of being periodic and ranging from high to low values.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are missing some details in your question, but you could always do something like $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2 & x\in [2n,2n+1) \\
-2 & x\in [2n+1,2n)
\end{cases} $$

for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Equivalently, you could take the Fourier Transform of $$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
2 & x\in [0,1) \\
-2 & x\in [-1,0)
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Actually this goes four up then four down

Comment: @KristofferRyhl True; until I know what OP is after I was guessing this is what they meant. There needs to be some more detail posted above to give a solid answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Square Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave). The simplest definition would probably be
$$f(x) = \textrm{sgn}(\sin x)$$
Where sgn$(x)$ is the sign function. Technically, this equals $0$ when $x=0$, so you may prefer the piecewise
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1 & : \sin x \ge 0 \\
-1 & : \sin x < 0
\end{array} \right.$$
If you don't like either of those, or want to figure out more, you could look into [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), which can define a square wave in terms of sine waves without any piecewise parts, and are generally just cool.